# How to interpret postfix logs on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, sendmail, fail2ban

I just installed postfix on my server which runs Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. I am a little confused as to how I should interpret the postfix logs located at `/var/log/mail.log`.

Firstly, one of the reasons I installed postfix was to that my cron jobs would be able to send me an email containing any errors or output. When this happens, it appears that Gmail is blocking the message because it thinks it's unsolicited email.

To test this, I set up a cronjob that simply echoes the word `test`.  This is my cron file:

```
MAILTO=example@gmail.com
44 13 * * * echo test
```

When this runs, here is what I see in the postfix logs:

```
Feb  7 13:44:01 prod postfix/pickup[22580]: AE4271627DB: uid=0 from=<root>
Feb  7 13:44:01 prod postfix/cleanup[23434]: AE4271627DB: message-id=<20150207184401.AE4271627DB@server.hostname.01>
Feb  7 13:44:01 prod postfix/qmgr[3539]: AE4271627DB: from=<root@server.hostname.01>, size=565, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb  7 13:44:01 prod postfix/smtp[23436]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400d:c03::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Feb  7 13:44:02 prod postfix/smtp[23436]: AE4271627DB: to=<example@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.171.27]:25, delay=1.2, delays=0.02/0.01/0.56/0.65, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.171.27] said: 550-5.7.1 [104.236.71.114      12] Our system has detected that this message is 550-5.7.1 likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail, 550-5.7.1 this message has been blocked. Please visit 550-5.7.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188131 for 550 5.7.1 more information. a3si7533488qas.19 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
Feb  7 13:44:02 prod postfix/cleanup[23434]: E62521627DC: message-id=<20150207184402.E62521627DC@server.hostname.01>
Feb  7 13:44:02 prod postfix/qmgr[3539]: E62521627DC: from=<>, size=3228, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb  7 13:44:02 prod postfix/bounce[23437]: AE4271627DB: sender non-delivery notification: E62521627DC
Feb  7 13:44:02 prod postfix/qmgr[3539]: AE4271627DB: removed
Feb  7 13:44:02 prod postfix/local[23439]: E62521627DC: to=<root@server.hostname.01>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Feb  7 13:44:02 prod postfix/qmgr[3539]: E62521627DC: removed
```

After this occurs, I do NOT receive the email in my Gmail account, and I see a new email message on my server at `/var/mail/root`:

```
From MAILER-DAEMON  Sat Feb  7 13:44:02 2015
Return-Path: <>
X-Original-To: root@server.hostname.01
Delivered-To: root@server.hostname.01
Received: by server.hostname.01 (Postfix)
    id E62521627DC; Sat,  7 Feb 2015 13:44:02 -0500 (EST)
Date: Sat,  7 Feb 2015 13:44:02 -0500 (EST)
From: MAILER-DAEMON@server.hostname.01 (Mail Delivery System)
Subject: Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender
To: root@server.hostname.01
Auto-Submitted: auto-replied
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
    boundary="AE4271627DB.1423334642/server.hostname.01"
Message-Id: <20150207184402.E62521627DC@server.hostname.01>

This is a MIME-encapsulated message.

--AE4271627DB.1423334642/server.hostname.01
Content-Description: Notification
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

This is the mail system at host server.hostname.01.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                   The mail system

<example@gmail.com>: host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.171.27] said:
    550-5.7.1 [104.236.71.114      12] Our system has detected that this
    message is 550-5.7.1 likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam
    sent to Gmail, 550-5.7.1 this message has been blocked. Please visit
    550-5.7.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188131
    for 550 5.7.1 more information. a3si7533488qas.19 - gsmtp (in reply to end
    of DATA command)

--AE4271627DB.1423334642/server.hostname.01
Content-Description: Delivery report
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; server.hostname.01
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: AE4271627DB
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; root@server.hostname.01
Arrival-Date: Sat,  7 Feb 2015 13:44:01 -0500 (EST)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; example@gmail.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Remote-MTA: dns; gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.7.1 [104.236.71.114      12] Our system has
    detected that this message is 550-5.7.1 likely unsolicited mail. To reduce
    the amount of spam sent to Gmail, 550-5.7.1 this message has been blocked.
    Please visit 550-5.7.1
    http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188131 for 550
    5.7.1 more information. a3si7533488qas.19 - gsmtp

--AE4271627DB.1423334642/server.hostname.01
Content-Description: Undelivered Message
Content-Type: message/rfc822

Return-Path: <root@server.hostname.01>
Received: by server.hostname.01 (Postfix, from userid 0)
    id AE4271627DB; Sat,  7 Feb 2015 13:44:01 -0500 (EST)
From: root@server.hostname.01 (Cron Daemon)
To: example@gmail.com
Subject: Cron <root@server> echo test
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ANSI_X3.4-1968
X-Cron-Env: <MAILTO=example@gmail.com>
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>
Message-Id: <20150207184401.AE4271627DB@server.hostname.01>
Date: Sat,  7 Feb 2015 13:44:01 -0500 (EST)

test

--AE4271627DB.1423334642/server.hostname.01--
```

I also have fail2ban installed on the server. When fail2ban blocks and IP address from attempting to login to my server, it sends me an email to let me know.  These are some of the headers from the email message:

```
Received: by server.hostname.01 (Postfix, from userid 0)
From: Fail2Ban <fail2ban@server.hostname.01>
To: example@gmail.com
Message-Id: <20150207160536.6BBAB1627DB@server.hostname.01>
```

When I search for that message ID in my mail logs, I see the following:

```
Feb  7 11:05:36 server postfix/cleanup[22079]: 6BBAB1627DB: message-id=<20150207160536.6BBAB1627DB@server.spirecollective.01>
Feb  7 11:05:36 server postfix/qmgr[3539]: 6BBAB1627DB: from=<fail2ban@server.spirecollective.01>, size=1951, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb  7 11:05:36 server postfix/smtp[22081]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400d:c03::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Feb  7 11:05:37 server postfix/smtp[22081]: 6BBAB1627DB: to=<example@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.171.26]:25, delay=1.7, delays=0.2/0/0.55/0.95, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.171.26] said: 550-5.7.1 [104.236.71.114      11] Our system has detected that this message is 550-5.7.1 not RFC 2822 compliant. To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail, 550-5.7.1 this message has been blocked. Please review 550 5.7.1 RFC 2822 specifications for more information. z1si7039105qar.33 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
Feb  7 11:05:37 server postfix/cleanup[22079]: EC2971627DC: message-id=<20150207160537.EC2971627DC@server.spirecollective.01>
Feb  7 11:05:37 server postfix/qmgr[3539]: EC2971627DC: from=<>, size=4514, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb  7 11:05:37 server postfix/bounce[22082]: 6BBAB1627DB: sender non-delivery notification: EC2971627DC
Feb  7 11:05:37 server postfix/qmgr[3539]: 6BBAB1627DB: removed
Feb  7 11:05:37 server postfix/local[22084]: EC2971627DC: to=<fail2ban@server.spirecollective.01>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0/0.01/0/0, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "fail2ban")
Feb  7 11:05:37 server postfix/qmgr[3539]: EC2971627DC: removed
```

This seems to imply that the message was blocked, just like the one sent as a result of the cron jobs, however, this message DOES appear in my Gmail inbox.

I was hoping someone could explain why fail2ban is able to successfully send email messages to Gmail but but my cron jobs are not.  I was also hoping someone could help me understand exactly what this log output means so I can better understand what's happening.  Maybe I have something configured wrong with postfix?

**UPDATE**

As per the comments, here is the full message header from one of the fail2ban messages that made it to my inbox, but shows as being blocked in the postfix logged. This is not the same message as was discussed in the previous part of this question, but it shows the exact same behavior:

```
Delivered-To: example@gmail.com
Received: by 10.25.23.137 with SMTP id 9csp1267799lfx;
        Sun, 8 Feb 2015 16:18:32 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.224.96.196 with SMTP id i4mr22411932qan.44.1423441111367;
        Sun, 08 Feb 2015 16:18:31 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <fail2ban@prod.spirecollective.01>
Received: from prod.spirecollective.01 ([104.236.71.114])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id 33si12196322qgi.19.2015.02.08.16.18.30
        for <example@gmail.com>;
        Sun, 08 Feb 2015 16:18:31 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: none (google.com: fail2ban@prod.spirecollective.01 does not designate permitted sender hosts) client-ip=104.236.71.114;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=none (google.com: fail2ban@prod.spirecollective.01 does not designate permitted sender hosts) smtp.mail=fail2ban@prod.spirecollective.01
Received: by prod.spirecollective.01 (Postfix, from userid 0)
    id 103C01627EF; Sun,  8 Feb 2015 19:18:30 -0500 (EST)
Subject: [Fail2Ban] ssh: banned 124.205.135.225 from prod.spirecollective.01
Date: Mon, 09 Feb 2015 00:18:29 +0000
From: Fail2Ban <fail2ban@prod.spirecollective.01>
To: example@gmail.com
Message-Id: <20150209001830.103C01627EF@prod.spirecollective.01>
```

Here is the entries from the postfix log for the same message:

```
Feb  8 19:18:30 prod postfix/pickup[2360]: 103C01627EF: uid=0 from=<fail2ban>
Feb  8 19:18:30 prod postfix/cleanup[3152]: 103C01627EF: message-id=<20150209001830.103C01627EF@prod.spirecollective.01>
Feb  8 19:18:30 prod postfix/qmgr[3539]: 103C01627EF: from=<fail2ban@prod.spirecollective.01>, size=2156, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb  8 19:18:31 prod postfix/smtp[3154]: 103C01627EF: to=<example@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.171.26]:25, delay=1.5, delays=0.16/0/0.55/0.77, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.171.26] said: 550-5.7.1 [104.236.71.114      11] Our system has detected that this message is 550-5.7.1 not RFC 2822 compliant. To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail, 550-5.7.1 this message has been blocked. Please review 550 5.7.1 RFC 2822 specifications for more information. 33si12196322qgi.19 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
Feb  8 19:18:31 prod postfix/bounce[3155]: 103C01627EF: sender non-delivery notification: 633B4162817
Feb  8 19:18:31 prod postfix/qmgr[3539]: 103C01627EF: removed
```

Comment: Did you read http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188131

Comment: Yes @etl, but that doesn't explain why mail would be delivered successfully by fail2ban but not from a cron job. The mail is coming from the same server in both cases.

Comment: Your post is incorrect. The fail2ban message ID is different than the logs you listed. Therefore, I highly doubt that Gmail replied the send with a bounce and you then see it in your inbox. There are a lots of difference in the small snippets of email headers you posted between the Cron email and the fail2ban emails - the sender for one is different.

Comment: Could it be that fail2ban sends directly out and not through your Postfix? In anycase, Gmail does not like your postfix server and there are probably 50+ possible reasons: no reverse DNS lookup, invalid sender domain, SPF, DKIM, etc. With altered information, I can't give a definite answer. `server.hostname.01` is definitely not a valid email domain.

Comment: What do you mean by "fail2ban sends directly out and not through Postfix"? How else would it send out? The fact that this is in the message heard from fail2ban made me think it uses postfix: `Received: by prod.spirecollective.01 (Postfix, from userid 0)`. It also says to use `sendmail` in the fail2ban config file. `server.hostname.01` is the hostname for my server, it's not an actual valid domain or anything like that? Does it have to be? If so, again, why can fail2ban send messages using that hostname but my cron jobs can't?

Comment: I don't know how you configured fail2ban but you haven't included any postfix logs that shows any fail2ban message been sent either. If you are going to forward emails to Gmail, your postfix will need to have a valid reverse DNS entry or it will consider your a spammer.

Comment: Ok. Yes I see now that the messages in the logs do not actually match the ones I am receiving from fail2ban. However I am pretty confident that fail2ban is using `sendmail` since that is in the config, it says the postfix line mentioned above in the message headers, and I have had fail2ban installed for a while, but just recently started receiving emails after I installed postfix.

Comment: I put the wrong ID in my original post, it is fixed now. You can see that the message ID that I received is also appearing in the postfix logs and appears to say it was undeliverable. How is that possible?

Comment: Hi, can you paste the **full** email header of fail2ban in gmail inbox. There are no **queue-id** in the headers above

Comment: Thanks @masegaloeh. Please see my update in the question for an example full message header. I still don't see a queue-id as you mentioned, would it be somewhere else?

Comment: Your failban message on gmail has queue-ID `103C01627EF`. Try to run command `grep 103C01627EF /path/to/mail.log.file`

Comment: I've added the output of this to the bottom of the question. Does that help?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for full-header of received email with queue-ID `103C01627EF` and its relevant maillog.

This log told us that gmail rejected the email. In theory, nothing would show up in your gmail Inbox. But in reality, gmail **may have accepts** the message and deliver it to your mailbox. The proof was the full header posted above.

What I want to says it, sometimes mail server was misbehaving (due to bug, discard policy, or other factors).

- They may reject you after DATA stage, but in reality the accept the email and deliver it to appropriate recipient. Your case was the example.
- They may accept the email first. After they scan it with an antivirus daemon, turns out the email contains virus. So, they drop it.

---

Now, the real question is why Gmail reject your email. Looks like the sender address `fail2ban@prod.spirecollective.01` wasn't properly FQDN-format. So, it's normal that Gmail would reject your email.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, but it still doesn't seem right to me. I am consistently receiving every email from `fail2ban@prod.spirecollective.01`, but I am not receiving a single email from my cronjobs which contain a sender of `root@prod.spirecollective.01`. Why would this be?

Comment: Only gmail can answer your question as their mail server who accept your message. My advice, please change the sender address to FQDN-one.